# Check if string matches dynamic regexp and find variables

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x

In django web app, user may define urls with dynamic parameters, for example:

> /users/:id

or

> /posts/:postid/:commentid

now, I have given strings, for example:
`/users/mysername` <- it matches `/users/:id` - how can I exstract "myusername" from it?
/users/mysuername/something <- doesn't match
/posts/10/382 - match, extract two variables - postid and commentid

my models.py:

```
class Server(BaseModel):
    url = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('URL'), max_length=64)
```

in my view, I want to compare request's PATH_INFO:

```
endpoint_url = request.META.get('PATH_INFO').lower().strip().lstrip('/')
```

lets say I have a Server model instance with url: /users/:someid
now, when request path is: /users/somestring0
I want to match it and extract variable someid to be "somestring0".

Parmeters may contain anything - except slash (/) probably.

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Try: `^\/users\/(\w+)$`

Comment: Where? There urls are dynamic - stored in the database, defined by user

Answer (score 0):

If these endpoints are registered in Django routes, maybe just use [resolver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) ?

```
from django.urls import resolve

match = resolve(my_url)
print(match.args)
print(match.kwargs)
```